# Why are two providers showing up in React Dev Tools

Tags: reactjs, react-devtools

In React Dev Tools, I'm seeing two providers:

[image]

As far as I know, I'm not doing anything weird when setting up the code:

```
ReactDom.render(
  <Provider store={store}> 
    <ConnectedRouter history={history} > 
      <Routes store={store} /> 
    </ConnectedRouter> 
  </Provider>, document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Is it possible that there's a bug in the tool, or am I committing a common error?

Comment: I have encountered this issue too, but it happens sporadically. It might be a bug in `React`.